# Mysterious misspelt R error in assign 'argumemt is not a character' after updating shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, lapply, assign

I am running a shiny app that basically generates SQL code for word-searches within a column 'WordText'.

While the code is working fine for other users running R 3.1.1, it has started throwing errors after I updated shiny.  Please note that I was running R 3.2.3 prior to updating shiny and the shiny app worked fine.

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Warning: Error in FUN: argumemt is not a character vector
Stack trace (innermost first):
    74: lapply
    73: paste8
    72: HTML
    71: assign
    70: renderUI [U:\00 R\Shiny - Coursera\08 Tech05/server.R#174]
    69: func
    68: output$key1A_main
     1: runApp
```

Also this is the first time I'm getting a stack trace! Not sure what triggered these.

The code snippet in question:

```
########### GENERATING MULTIPLE OUTPUTS ################
#### MULTIPLE KEYWORD DEPENDENCIES !!!
lapply(1:5, function(x){

## Defining as many functions as the number of times displayed - Word Search Generator, (Complaints and Monthly Trends TAB )  X2 - SS + TD

output[[sprintf("key%dA_main",x)]] <- output[[sprintf("key%dA_main_SS_1",x)]] <- output[[sprintf("key%dA_main_SS_2",x)]]  <- 
output[[sprintf("key%dA_main_TD_1",x)]] <- output[[sprintf("key%dA_main_TD_2",x)]]  <- renderUI({

## Main Keyword Case Summary LIKE Statement
assign(sprintf("key%dA_start",x),
if(input[[sprintf("key%dA",x)]]=="") {""}
else {HTML(paste0("(",br(),"WordText like '%",input[[sprintf("key%dA",x)]],"%'",br(),em(sprintf("/* Main Keyword %d */",x)),br()))}
) 

## 'AND' and Starting Parenthesis if any dependent keywords   
assign(sprintf("key%dA_start_OR",x),
if(nchar(input[[sprintf("key%d_temp_1",x)]],allowNA = TRUE)==0) {" "} else {paste0("AND",br()," (",br())  }
)   


## 1st Dependent Keyword Case Summary LIKE Statment      
assign(sprintf("key%dA_first",x),
if(nchar(input[[sprintf("key%d_temp_1",x)]],allowNA = TRUE)==0) {" "} else {paste0("WordText like '%", input[[sprintf("key%d_temp_1",x)]], "%'", br())}
)   

## All other Dependent Keywords Case Summary LIKE Statments
assign(sprintf("key%dA_other",x),HTML(
lapply(2:10, function(i) {
xy <- input[[sprintf("key%d_temp_%d",x, i)]]
if (nchar(xy,allowNA = TRUE)>0) paste0("OR WordText like '%", xy, "%'", br())
else " "
})#END lapply
))      

## Ending Parenthesis if any dependent keywords   
assign(sprintf("key%dA_end_OR",x),
if(nchar(input[[sprintf("key%d_temp_1",x)]],allowNA = TRUE)==0) {" "} else {paste0(")",br(),em(sprintf("/* Dependent Keyword(s) for Keyword %d */",x)))  }
)      


## Ending Parenthesis for entire criteria (Main Keyword + dependent keywords)   
assign(sprintf("key%dA_end",x),
if(input[[sprintf("key%dA",x)]]=="") {" "} else {HTML(paste0(br(),")"))  }
)    

## Collating outputs
HTML(paste0(  get(sprintf("key%dA_start",x))
, get(sprintf("key%dA_start_OR",x))
, get(sprintf("key%dA_first",x))
, get(sprintf("key%dA_other",x))
, get(sprintf("key%dA_end_OR",x))
, get(sprintf("key%dA_end",x))) )


})#END renderUI 

})#END LAPPLY
```

The session info is as below:

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] scales_0.3.0      ggplot2_2.0.0     RODBC_1.3-12      shinythemes_1.0.1 DT_0.1            shiny_0.13.0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3      digest_0.6.9     mime_0.4         plyr_1.8.3       grid_3.2.3       R6_2.1.1         jsonlite_0.9.19  xtable_1.8-0     gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5     tools_3.2.3     
[12] htmlwidgets_0.5  munsell_0.4.2    httpuv_1.3.3     colorspace_1.2-6 htmltools_0.3
```